# Sending a copy of email to sender in PHP

Tags: php

I have a contact form in a website that i inherited to work on. I do not know the source. I need users to receive a copy of the email with a different message. Can anyone help?

HERE IS THE PHP

```
 // Adding e-mail headers
    $headers = "";
    if (FROM_EMAIL !== '') {
        $headers .= 'From: '.FROM_EMAIL."\r\n";
    }
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$contact_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'."\r\n";

    /*
     * Formatting message.
     * It can be customizable in any way you like.
     */
    $title = 'Contact Form - New Message from '.$contact_name;
    $message = 'Hi,'."\n\n"
        .'You have received new message from your website. Check details below:'."\n\n"
        .'Sender\'s IP address: '.getIp()."\n\n"
        .'Name: '.$contact_name."\n\n"
        .'Title: '.$contact_sex."\n\n"
        .'E-mail: '.$contact_email."\n\n"
        .'Phone number: '.$contact_tel."\n\n"
        .'Selected department: '.$contact_department."\n\n"
        .'Message:'."\n\n"
        .$contact_message;


    // Mail it!
    $result = mail(TO_EMAIL, $title, $message, $headers);

    // Notify contact form about result of sending.
    if ($result) {
        $json['result'] = 'OK';
    } else {
        $json['result'] = 'SEND_ERROR';
    }
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    echo json_encode($json);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
// Mail it!
$result = mail(TO_EMAIL, $title, $message, $headers);
```

With this:

```
$differentMessage = 'This is a string that contains sth and after this we append the old message' . $message; 

// Mail it!
$result = mail(TO_EMAIL, $title, $message, $headers);
// Mail a copy
mail($contact_email, $title, $differentMessage, $headers);
```

Note that the header will stay the same (replay to), but this should give you an idea about how to modify variables and send a second email.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian . sorry for my poor knowledge. Where  do I set the variables precisely ? thanks

Comment: Thank you  Sebastian . it works  very Well . like MAGIC. I may reach out to you for some tweaking if that's OK with you .